# How to import a string in python and analyze and refactor that?

Tags: python, refactoring

I need to import a string (a piece of python code) into python and analyze it to improve that. In other words, I want to **refactor** a piece of code that imported as a string.

How can I analyze, understand and rebuild a code? Is there any *library* or *algorithm* to help me?

At the moment, I'm working on a project that refactors **Classes** via methods *inline* and *push down*.

For example:

Input:

```
class PizzaDelivery:
    # ...
    def getRating(self):
        return 2 if self.moreThanFiveLateDeliveries() else 1
  
    def moreThanFiveLateDeliveries(self):
        return self.numberOfLateDeliveries > 5
```

Output:

```
class PizzaDelivery:
  # ...
  def getRating(self):
    return 2 if self.numberOfLateDeliveries > 5 else 1
```

Comment: You want a routine that can automatically and intelligently analyze code and refactor it? I lterally just read about [this](https://sourcery.ai/) in another post. Maybe it can help you?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want. But I have to write my own code instead of using plugins or apps.

Comment: it can be problem too broad for this portal.